# How to put number of html elements from ajax response into a variable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How to add the resulting number of html elements in an ajax response to a variable, and then write html based on variable value:

```
success:
function(result){
var data = $(result).find('h3').lenght;
if (data > 0){
  $("div").html(result);
}
}
```

If i log.console it displays the correct number of h3 elements in the console.

```
console.log($(result).find('h3').lenght)
```

Comment: it should be length not lenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
if ($(result).find('h3').length){
  $("div").html(result);
}
```